# Apply a PostSharp aspect to all methods in class to Log method name

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I would like to create an attribute, that I want to apply to a class.
In this class, if a method was called, in the `OnEntry` and `OnExit` methodof postsharp, I want to log the exact method name like this:

> "GetPartners starting..."

or

> "GetPartners finished..."

or if an exception occured:

> "Exception occured in GetPartners method"

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options available to enable methods tracing.

First of all, you can use an existing PostSharp Diagnostics Pattern Library and just add and configure the `[Log]` attribute from that library: [Adding detailed tracing](http://doc.postsharp.net/logging).

If you want to create your own attribute, then an example is available here: ["PostSharp.Samples.CustomLogging"](http://samples.postsharp.net/#PostSharp.Samples.CustomLogging/README.md).

Basically you need to derive from the class [`OnMethodBoundaryAspect`](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_onmethodboundaryaspect) and override methods `OnEntry`, `OnExit`, `OnException` to write your messages.

For better performance you can prepare the corresponding messages during compile-time and reuse them at run-time in your handlers, as shown in the example:

```
public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
{
    string methodName = method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name;
    this.enteringMessage = "Entering " + methodName;
    this.exitingMessage = "Exiting " + methodName;
}
```